# iOS VST audio plugin support

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-recording, vst

As an Objective C developer, is there a library or another smart "easy" way to get VST plugins to run on iOS?

(Please improve tagging if you have any suggesions. )

Comment: Aren't VST's DLLs?
(hint, yes, they are!) this is also why vst's do not generally run on other operating systems that Windows

Comment: Yeah, this will never work. Give up now. Only hope would be for the original creator/vendor to release a library compiled for iOS, but it would hardly be a VST plugin at that point.

Comment: @Timothy Groote: VST plugins aren't limited to Windows. They run fine on Mac and Linux.

Comment: The snake's in the wording ; i said "generally" for a reason ;)
You need to do a bunch of emulation in order to get those things to run, meaning that when you get it to work, the performance will be sub-par with windows.

Comment: From what I remember, according to the VST spec, VST plugins can be DLL's for windows, .so files for linux, and I-forget-what for Macs.  Each system has it's own way of supporting code libraries (shared object files, dynamic link libraries, etc.), and there are even some clever ways of using VST DLLs on Linux (relying on memory here: I think Ardour uses WINE libraries to pre-process VST DLLs on Linux [https://community.ardour.org/building_vst_support]).

Comment: @TimothyGroote VST's can *definitely* be built as native libraries for linux/mac (and even 32/64 bit for both platforms).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code, you could theoretically plug it into an AudioUnit graph. This actually isn't that hard to do, but again, if you have the source you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Otherwise there is no chance that an Intel binary could be made to run on iOS, or that even if you could the performance would be real time on an iPhone or iPad.